# Is it possible to know the old value of an element within the directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to know the elements **old value** and **new value** when it is changed dynamically?

An example, I have a button with value 190

```
<button name="btn1" directiveX>190</button>
```

And this button will be changed dynamically by socket.io. When its changed, I need to compare these values, if the new value higher then the old value is.

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `$watch` the value in your scope, it will give you the old value and the new value. So your link function in the directive would look like this

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.$watch("foo", function(newVal, oldVal) {
           //logic based on oldVal
         }
      }
```

And then in your HTML

```
<button name="btn1" directiveX>{{foo}}</button>
```

See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: ty, but newVal and oldVal are always equal?

Comment: They will be equal the first time the `$watch` runs, but as the model is changed after that, it will give you the new value and the old value. If the model (`foo`) is being updated outside of Angular, make sure you are calling `scope.$apply()` afterward so Angular can rerun its stuff based on the new model.